# how to call a method of superclass of an activity in alertDialog (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, super

When hitting "Back" button in device on a specific fragment, I want to alert user and let them decide to hide the app or stay. Here the code segment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if(f instanceof PlanListFragment){
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_Cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // I want to call this: **super.onBackPressed()**; but super is not recognized at all here.
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

As commented above, how can I call this "supper.onBackPressed()" method when clicking the "Ok" button?

Thanks in advance!

Shawn

Comment: So you want to dismiss the dialog and close the activity when user press "ok".?

Answer (score 0):

super.onBackPressed is not recognized because you're currently constructing a DialogInterface.OnClickListener. You could simply declare a variable myActivity before constructing the said listener and call onBack on that one.

```
Activity activity = this; 
 builder.setNegativeButton...
{
      ...
      activity.onBackPressed();
      ... 
 }
```

Replace "Activity" with whatever Fragment you're in.

// **Update**

May write a new Method which does the super.onBackPressed() call.

Comment: onBackPressed() is already in MyActivity. what I need is to find a way to get its super class, something something like : Activity super_activity = this.supper; I tried this:  Activity super_activity = this.getParent(); but super_activity is null.

Comment: I think you can set the parent like this in your manifest: [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)
I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for / what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

As [DerDingens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829607/how-to-call-a-method-of-superclass-of-an-activity-in-alertdialog-android-studio/44830109#44830109) says in her answer, super.onBackPressed is not recognized because you're currently constructing a DialogInterface.OnClickListener.

You can call ActivityName.super.onBackPressed() if you still in the same Activity. This will call the super method only.

Example:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(strExit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                CallActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (condition == true){

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setTitle("Unsaved data");
        dialog.setMessage("You'll lose any unsaved data");

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                goBack();
            }
        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        dialog.create().show();

    }else{
        goBack();
    }
}
private void goBack(){ 
    super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

I did this earlier today and this seems to work perfectly. I'm not sure if it should but it does.